# HTML e-mail - Outlook 2013 adding blank spaces between rows

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email

I have an HTML e-mail that is breaking on Outlook 2013. Between every row, there is a white space: [Photo](http://s27.postimg.org/44ofejy5v/break.jpg)

Every image is set to display: block, I have added border-collapse: collapse to the table and page-break-before: always to table rows but nothing had effect...

Comment: can you post some code? that would help remove validation errors, etc as potential culprits.

Answer (score 1):

set the cellpadding, spacing and border to 0

Answer (score 1):

without seeing your code and knowing exactly what you have, below is sample of what I use and usually works in Outlook:

```
<table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr>
<td style="display:block; border-collapse:collapse;">
  <img alt="Sample Image" src="http://placehold.it/230x150.png" width="230" style="display:block;" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Outlook ads a default font size of 13px.  If you add a style of font-size: 1px and line height of 1px on the  and the  this might fix it.
This fixed it for me when I ran into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

A pretty hacky way of fixing that is using `margin-bottom: -10px;` or w.e

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps specifically set the padding/margin to 0px.